# Вывод информации в Excel построчно

Tags: python, xml, pandas, excel

Помогите пожалуйста вывести информацию из xml файла в Excel построчно (в каждой строке своя информация из xml), у меня получается так: в колонке КН выдает всю информацию в одну строку, в в колонках Number и Type выдает только последнее найденное значение и его же записывает в Excel.

На скрине показываю как отрабатываются print(Number, Type), print(dhdh) и print(page_1) и как записывается в Excel. А хотелось бы записать информацию построчно и всю информацию, которую выдает print.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код в Python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd


file_path = r'F:\Python\XML\2'
excel_file = r'F:\Python\XML\2\2.xlsx'


page_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = [])

for path in Path(file_path).rglob('*.XML'):
        with open(path, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as parse:
            xml = parse.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, features="xml")
            for param in soup.find_all('num:OldNumber'):
                    Number = param.get('Number')
                    Type = param.get('Type')
                    print(Number, Type)
            for dt in soup.find_all('PrevCadastralNumbers'):
                dhdh = dt.text
                print(dhdh)
            Cad = {'КН':f'{dhdh}',
                    'Number':f'{Number}',
                    'Type':f'{Type}',}
page_1 = pd.concat([page_1, pd.DataFrame.from_records([Cad])], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
print(page_1)
with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='openpyxl', mode = 'w') as writer:
    page_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='КН',index=True)
```

XML выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="EGRP_Reestr_Extract_Gkn_OKS_07_Common.xsl"?>
<KPOKS xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/outgoing/kpoks/4.0.1" xmlns:smev="urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/supplementary/commons/1.0.1" xmlns:num="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/numbers/1.0" xmlns:adrs="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/address-output/4.0.1" xmlns:spa="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/entity-spatial/5.0.1" xmlns:param="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/parameters-oks/2.0.1" xmlns:cer="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/certification-doc/1.0" xmlns:doc="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/document-output/4.0.1" xmlns:flat="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/assignation-flat/1.0.1" xmlns:ch="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-ru/commons/complex-types/cultural-heritage/2.0.1">
  <Realty>
    <Flat CadastralNumber="52:21:0000103:5144" State="06" DateCreated="2014-11-12">
      <CadastralBlock>52:21:0000103</CadastralBlock>
      <ObjectType>002001003000</ObjectType>
      <ParentCadastralNumbers>
        <CadastralNumberOKS>52:21:0000103:200</CadastralNumberOKS>
      </ParentCadastralNumbers>
      <PrevCadastralNumbers>
        <CadastralNumber>52:21:0000103:3569</CadastralNumber>
        <CadastralNumber>52:21:0000103:3591</CadastralNumber>
      </PrevCadastralNumbers>
      <OldNumbers>
        <num:OldNumber Type="01" Number="7062" />
        <num:OldNumber Type="02" Number="3651654" />
      </OldNumbers>
    </Flat>
  </Realty>
</KPOKS>
```

Comment: В Cad -  dhdh, Number и Type должны быть списками, в которые вы, на каждой итерации цикла, докладываете полученные значения.

Comment: Можно было для поиска использовать стандартный модуль xml.etree.ElementTree, вместо BeautifulSoup. Да и вместо тяжеловесного pandas достаточно было openpyxl.

Comment: Списком тоже пробовал через .append и .extend, также добавлял '\n'.join() и только через .split получилось разделить, но все равно записывает в excel последнее значение, а не все данные в столбик.

Comment: Как мне кажется, могу ошибаться, проблема в записи в excel, где то тут:  

Cad = {'КН':f'{dhdh}',
        'Number':f'{edh}',
        'Type':f'{Type}',}

page_1 = pd.concat([page_1, pd.DataFrame.from_records([Cad])], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
print(page_1)
with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='openpyxl', mode = 'w') as writer:
    page_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='КН',index=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

file_path = r'F:\Python\XML\2'
excel_file = r'F:\Python\XML\2\2.xlsx'

page_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[])

for path in Path(file_path).rglob('*.XML'):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as parse:
        xml = parse.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, features="xml")
        for param in soup.find_all('num:OldNumber'):
            Number = param.get('Number')
            Type = param.get('Type')
            for right in soup.find_all('PrevCadastralNumbers'):
                for child_2 in right.findChildren(['CadastralNumber'], recursive = False):
                    dhdh = child_2.text
                    Cad = {'КН': f'{dhdh}', 'Number': f'{Number}', 'Type': f'{Type}'}
                    page_1 = pd.concat([page_1, pd.DataFrame.from_records([Cad])], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
print(page_1)
with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='openpyxl', mode='w') as writer:
    page_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='КН', index=True)
```